# Where to install Public TLS/SSL Certificate for private service in AWS Cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-eks, tls1.2, nat

A 3rd party service (think banking service, for instance) recommends it's clients to use SSL/TLS certificate for secure communication.

I have a private service hosted in private subnet in AWS VPC. This service initiates a conversation with this 3rd-party service in the internet via NAT Gateway. Where do I place the public SSL/TLS certificate of this 3rd party service if:

- I were to host this service in EC2 instance in private subnet?
- I were to host this service in private kubernetes/EKS cluster?

In short, the crux of the problem is about the service being in a private cluster and that it is the one initiating the request that needs to be encrypted using the public TLS Certificate given by the 3rd-party service provider.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't enough information in the question to provide specific guidance. Specifics include, what language and platform are you working in? Is this certificate just a public cert you need to trust or do you need to do mutual auth and store a private key? Is the public cert of your 3rd party signed by a CA that's generally trusted or is self-signed?

Answer (score 0):

Adding SSL/TLS for private is bit tricky process. For

> I were to host this service in EC2 instance in private subnet?

You can put servers in ALB and then add SSL from ACM in listeners.

More info on the situation will be helpful for better solutions

Comment: The crux of the problem is about the service being in a private cluster and that it is the one initiating the request that needs to be encrypted.